# snake case style in protobuff generated by grpc proto3

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, grpc-go, proto3

Is it possible to change default model of `proto3` from CamelCase to snake_case in grpc?

example :

file `anyproto.proto`

```
...
message Request {
  bool RequestStatus = 1;
  string RequestMessage = 2
}
...
```

now the `protoc -I. --go_out=plugins=grpc:. anyproto.proto` command generate this model:

file : `anyproto.pb.go`

```
type Request struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    RequestStatus  bool    `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=requestStatus,proto3" json:"requestStatus,omitempty"`
    RequestMessage string  `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=requestMessage,proto3" json:"requestMessage,omitempty"`
}
```

I want to change style of `requestStatus` and `requestMessage` to `request_status` and `request_message`

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, but this isn't a good idea. It's against [Go's naming convention](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments). You could say it's "just generated code", but you generate the code so you can use it in "your" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/style#message_and_field_names
Quoted from link:

> Use CamelCase (with an initial capital) for message names – for example, SongServerRequest. Use underscore_separated_names for field names (including oneof field and extension names) – for example, song_name.

```
message SongServerRequest {
  required string song_name = 1;
}
```

Comment: yes, actually I wanted to use camelCase in `proto` and result be `snake_case`, but with your answer I found the real solution;)

Comment: I found this solution creating language inconsistency among generated dialects: python code will use song_name; js and dart use songName. Very annoying